# Meaning of じゃろ and じゃろう

Tags: grammar, etymology, dialects, copula, role-language

> カトちゃんだって、実際は別に毎日長さんに怒られてるわけじゃない**じゃろ**から、本当は　”人気者**で**怒られない人”　**じゃろう**ね。
>   In reality it's not really the case that even Katochan gets told off by Chou everyday so, in truth, people who don't get told off by popular people ????

What do じゃろ and じゃろう mean in the sentence above? My guess is that it is a negative form of だろ, but if that's the case then I can't make the clause after から make any sense.

If it is a negative だろ then why use じゃないじゃろ rather than just じゃろ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, じゃろ and じゃろう are だろ and だろう, but in another dialect. Other forms include やろ and やろう. If you're wondering how they could all come about, they originally come from であろう. In ancient times, some dialects (including the standard, I believe) pronounced で what would be written as じぇ now, and so their であろう contracted naturally to じゃろう. やろう comes from じゃろう in a manner similar to what some dialects of English display. (Note that they're all from である, and indeed である has the alternative standard form だ as well as dialectal forms や and じゃ.) One last point: じゃろう is also sometimes used by old men in fiction to show that they are old men, but I don't think that's what's going on here.

And one last thing: a negative だろう would be ～ないだろう, ～なかろう, or (after a dictionary form or ～ます stem [dictionary form for godan, stem for ichidan]) ～まい. The latter two are literary.

Comment: Could I also please ask how to interpret the で in bold? I still can't make the final clause make sense. Is it "among" or "by" or something else.

Comment: @user3856370 I'm afraid I'm not sure myself.

Comment: @user3856370 Even though it's about the same quote, you can ask that as a separate question.